# Ionic 2 Native Audio No sound on Android

Tags: android, audio, ionic2

I have created a simple app in Ionic that uses Native Audio to play a single MP3-file. The code:

```
export class MyApp{

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private nativeAudio:NativeAudio) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('24', 'assets/klamydihahaha.mp3',1,1,0.1).then(
          (data)=>{
              alert(data);
            this.nativeAudio.play('24',()=>{alert("done")});
          },(error)=>{
              alert(error);
          }
      )
    });
  }
}
```

I run this on my Sony Xperia-device with Android 6.0 using

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

The alert-message will first show "ok", it will wait and then the message "done" will show. But there is no sound. The MP3 file works fine. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

May be the cordova API is not included with your command

Instead type this command

```
ionic cordova run android --emulator
```

or

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```